# RShiny : Error in paste0: Object not found

Tags: r, shiny

So, I'm currently converting my R script which runs just perfect into a RShiny app. The code is very long and I can't share it all but it involves forecasting various variables under different scenarios. While running it as an R code, I load equations from .Rdata file which has all equations & coefficients stored. However, when I;m trying to do it in Rshiny, it says object not found. Here eq_asset is the equation for asset variable I'm loading, pfw_test is a database. Error is Error in paste0: object 'z' not found which is coming from equation I'm loading because when I type equation (not load it), it runs just fine. I've tried loading equations .Rdata file in server, in UI etc but the same error shows up.

[image]

Comment: loading it in the UI won't do anything, you could load it in your global environment, before the server function

Comment: @Vida I did that too but didn't work.

Comment: I can't help, Try to provide a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)